# hist vs histogram function in r cran

Tags: r, function, histogram

I was able to make a nice looking histogram by accidentally using a function "histogram" (e.g., histogram(myvector)) in R. I closed out of R, opened the same script 5 minutes later on the same computer, and now R is telling me no function found. The function hist(), which I usually use, gives a slightly different looking histogram in terms of placement of axis labels and using frequency rather than percent on the y axis.

Just curious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mystery `histogram` function was probably in package `lattice` (though there are literally hundreds out there).  Did you do `library("lattice")` in your earlier session?

Comment: no, on my first session I started with an empty document. And I opened up the code 5 minutes later with no modifications. I've used lattice in the past though, several months ago, maybe my computer chose to remember?

Comment: There is a history file, generally hidden.  A seperate version can exist in each directory.  Still, I don't think you are likely to explain what happened.

Comment: THANKS GUYS! Figured it out. Of all random things, I did open the package Teaching Demo to show how you can roll a dice in R. After I used the function dice, but not before, I could use the histogram function

Comment: That had lattice as a dependency. That would explain it.

Answer (score 3):

The `hist` function is part of base R:

```
R> hist
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("hist")
<bytecode: 0x28fd968>
<environment: namespace:graphics>
```

The histogram function is (more than likely) part of the lattice package

```
R> library(lattice)
R> histogram
function (x, data, ...) 
UseMethod("histogram")
<environment: namespace:lattice>
```

Did you load lattice package? If not, what packages did you load? Look at your `.Rhistory` file if you can't remember. Alternatively, you can search all possible packages using `??histogram`

Comment: So `TeachingDemos` loaded `lattice` for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you type

```
??histogram
```

at the R prompt it gives you a list of all the packages with a function named histogram.  The one you were using was probably from lattice.